# How do I debug Invalid Input cypher queries when configuring relationships? (Neo4j OGM)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Going through the Neo4j-OGM tutorial [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/tutorial/), as soon as I wire in the @Relationship clause, I start getting the following Invalid Input error:

```
 WARN [main] (Neo4jSession.java:550) - Error executing query : Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError - Invalid input '|'
: expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^'
, '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']' (line 1, column 105 (offset: 
104))
"MATCH (n:`Subject`) WHERE ID(n) = { id } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)<-[r_c1:`CURRICULUM`]-(d1:`Department`) | [ r_c1, d1 ] ] ]"                                                                                                         
                                                                                                         ^. Rolling back transaction.
```

This error occurs when the DepartmentDataService attempts to do a find of the Department. I'm new enough to Neo4j that I'm not sure how the proper formatting of the relationship return should be presented.

How do I go about figuring out what I misinterpreted from the tutorial?

**Versions:**

1. Neo4j: 3.3.6 *(neo4j, neo4j-kernel)*
2. Neo4j-OGM: 3.1.2 *(neo4j-ogm-core, neo-ogm-bolt-driver)*

**Department.java**

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class Department implements HasId<Long> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  String name;

  @Relationship(type = "CURRICULUM")
  Set<Subject> subjects;

  public Department() {
    super();
  }

  public Department(final String name, final Subject s) {
    this.name = name;
    if (s != null) {
      subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
      subjects.add(s);
    }
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Set<Subject> getSubjects() {
    return subjects;
  }

  public void setSubjects(final Set<Subject> subjects) {
    this.subjects = subjects;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Department [name=" + name + ", subjects=" + subjects + "]";
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Department other = (Department) obj;
    if (name == null) {
      if (other.name != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
```

**Subject.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class Subject implements HasId<Long>{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  String name;

  @Relationship(type="CURRICULUM", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  Department department;

  public Subject(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
  }

  public void setDepartment(final Department department) {
    this.department = department;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Subject other = (Subject) obj;
    if (name == null) {
      if (other.name != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

**DepartmentDataService.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;

public class DepartmentDataService {

  private Class<Department> getEntityType() {
    return Department.class;
  }

  private static final int DEPTH_LIST = 0;

  private static final int DEPTH_ENTITY = 1;

  protected Session session = Neo4jSessionFactory.getInstance().getNeo4jSession();

  public List<Department> findAll() {
    final Collection<Department> results = session.loadAll(getEntityType(), DEPTH_LIST);
    return new ArrayList<Department>(results);
  }

  public Department find(final long id) {
    return session.load(getEntityType(), id, DEPTH_ENTITY);
  }

  public void delete(final long id) {
    session.delete(session.load(getEntityType(), id));
  }

  public Department createOrUpdate(final Department entity) {
      session.save(entity, DEPTH_ENTITY);
      return find(entity.getId());
  }

}
```

Comment: Regarding the query and the error, the query compiles and executes with 3.3.6 (there's one extra nesting of []'s that is unnecessary around the pattern comprehension, though), so the query itself isn't problematic.

Comment: I'm using 3.3.6 and I can't get it to compile / run... What am I not understanding?

Comment: That should run fine in the browser. In my answer below I point out that this is an OGM issue.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is coming from OGM code, so it looks like it doesn't understand pattern comprehensions.

[There's a bug around this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/496), unsure if it's the cause for this issue as well, but a good place to start looking.

As far as a workaround, you may want to replace usage of pattern comprehensions with MATCHes and collects().